# Android cannot get relative layout to place in correct position

Tags: java, android, mobile, layout

I cannot seem to position a relative layout based on the margins being set. Android seems to be placing the image at the top left corner of the screen for some reason.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(super.getContext());
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.topMargin=100;
params.leftMargin=259;
this.addView(iv, params);
```

Ideally the image should be placed at 100,259 - however, it appears to be positioned at 0,0.
The "this" reference in my code is a Framelayout.

Comment: How about using `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`?

Comment: Instead of 'this', try referencing the parent layout. Even if it is the main layout.

Comment: Thanks suitianshi - that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(super.getContext());
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
this.addView(iv, params);
iv.setX(259);
iv.setY(100);
```